# Calculating the expected hitting time of a specific birth and death chain

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am working with a specific birth and death chain, defined as follows.

Consider a set of states $X = \{0,1,2,...,n\}$, where $x^* \in (0,n)$ is a recurrent state. Transition probabilities are defined as follows:

$P_{i,j} = \left\{\begin{array}{lc} 1-p_i & \text{ if } i = j+1 \\ p_i & \text{ if } i = j \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{array}\right., \forall i,j \neq \{0,x^*,n\} \in X.$

Given that $x^*$ is a recurrent state, $P_{x^*,x^*}=1$. Moreover, $P_{0,0}=0$, and also $P_{n,n}=0$.

I am calculating the expected hitting time starting from any state $x < x^*$ (i.e., the hitting time from below). I call this value $\eta_{x,x^*}$ in line with standard notation on Markov Chains.

Starting from the constraint that $\eta_{x^*,x^*} =0$, I retrieved $\eta_{x^*-1,x^*} = \frac{1}{1-P_{x^*-1,x^*-1}}$, and then

$\eta_{x^*2,x^*} = \frac{1}{1-P_{x^*-2,x^*-2}} + \frac{P_{x^*-2,x^*-1}}{(1-P_{x^*-1,x^*-1})(1-P_{x^*-2,x^*-2})},$

$\eta_{x^*-3,x^*} = \frac{1}{1-P_{x^*-3,x^*-3}} \left(1 + \frac{P_{x^*-3,x^*-2}}{1-P_{x^*-2,x^*-2}} + \frac{P_{x^*-3,x^*-2}P_{x^*-2,x^*-1}}{(1-P_{x^*-1,x^*-1})(1-P_{x^*-2,x^*-2})}\right).$

Proceeding backward, I came up with this general formula for any state $x < x^*$:

$$ \eta_{x,x^*} = \frac{1}{1-P_{x,x}} \left(1 + \sum_{i=x}^{x^*-2}\prod_{l=x}^i\frac{P_{l,l+1}}{1- P_{l+1,l+1}} \right), $$

Can someone tell me if this formula is correct?

Thank you in advance,
I am happy to give more details in case they are needed.

Comment: Note that I just deleted the second part of the question which is more problematic, and so, I could ask it in a second question.

Comment: If I unterstand your question correctly, you simply want to calculate the sum of expectation of geometric distributed random variables. This is nothing else but $1/(1-p_i) + 1/(1-p_{i+}) + \ldots + 1/(1-p_{x^*-1})$, if you start in $i$. These r.v. are independent (her we need some M.C. theory). So we get even more if we want.

Comment: If I understand what you mean, I think that my random variables are not independent, e.g., $\eta_{x,x*}$ depends on $\eta_{x+1,x*}$, and so forth. Indeed, your formula does not match my example for $\eta_{x^*-2,x^*}$. I am more looking for a double check on my calculation from $\eta_{x^*-2,x^*}$ to $\eta_{x^*-k,x^*}$, and then generalizing the formula to a state $x<x^*$ (the last passage you see in the question).

Comment: The problem seems to be: What is your exact definition of hitting time? This can be done with first entrance times which are stopping times. And yes, your formula is different from mine. I have no idea how do you get your formula.

Comment: Sorry, if I was not clear. As a definition of expected hitting time, I use the standard one, meaning, the first time $x^*$ is hit when starting from a state $x$. To be formal, given $H_{x^*} = min\{t\in\{0,1,2,…\}:x(t)=j\}$, $\eta_{x,x^*}=E(H_{x^*}|x(0)=x)$.
I calculated my formula starting from $\eta_{x^*-1,x^*}$ (which I know), then calculating  $\eta_{x^*-2,x^*}$... $\eta_{x^*-k,x^*}$, and then generalizing to $\eta_{x,x^*}$.

Comment: By the strong Markov property (f.i. J.R.Norris, Markov Chains (1997), p. 19 ff) for this simple MC we get as a consequence, that $H_1, H_2-H_1, \ldots, H_{x^*}-H_{x^*-1}$ are independent and geometric distributed. There must be an error in your formula. It's impossible (and uninteresting) for me to find the error.